# ReferenceError foo is undefined (in IE and firefox)

Tags: function, internet-explorer, firefox, undefined, referenceerror

Looked through the questions and there are few similar ones on the subject of "ReferenceError foo is not defined". However, I'm not able to detect the error in my code and get it working. It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in IE, Opera and Firefox:

The code in the HTML

```
<a href="javascript:foo(1)" target="_parent">
```

calls a javascript placed in the header as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/include/script.js"></script>
```

which is defined as the following:

```
function foo(language){
    url = window.parent.location.href;
    parts = url.split('/');
    page = parts[3];

    newUrl = "";

    if (language == 1){
        newUrl = "http://www.site1.com/" + page;
    } else if (language == 2){
        newUrl = "http://www.site2.com/" + page;
    } else{
        newUrl = "http://www.site3.com/" + page;
    }

    window.parent.window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

Reading the related questions I tested to change to `window.foo = function(language){...}`, but it didn't help.

Seems straight forward and as simple as it gets, but of some reason foo is undefined in IE and firefox.

Should be added that the javascript is in the "top.html" which is an embeded iframe for each page. Somehow chrome manages this while IE doesn't (but the  script works if I browse to http://www.site1.com/top.html and click on the button calling redirect(language);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the link is targeted (has a `target="_parent"` bit).

This means that it runs in the scope of the target window, not in the window it's in. And there is no function named `foo` there.

Answer (score 0):

It look like your link is in a "iframe" tag, but the `foo` function is defined in top-level window object's scope.

There a two ways to fix this:

You should use `window.partent` to reference the top-level window object, try to change the link to

```
<a href="javascript:window.partent.foo(1)" target="_parent">
```

Or, move the function code to the same html file's head tag as the link.

By the way, you should use `var` keyword to declare variables.

Comment: Well, I had tested both those alternatives and neither helped. Actually adding window.parent to the call made the code stop working in chrome as well.

Copying the code directly into the top.html (rather then the relative URL via <script></script> tagging) was the first thing I tested, but it still says "undefined function" in IE and firefox. 

PS. Have also tested to explicitly declare the variable, just to be on the safe side, but that did not matter as well.

Comment: OK, now it's clear that there's something declarative. When I put in a function test(){ alter("TEST");} in the same place, it works to call it! But foo is still undefined. Starts to get on my nerves.

Comment: Aha... Got it. A stupid error that wasn't that obvious to me: it was "target="_parent" which caused the error. It was there in the beginning when the link was static and now that I removed it, it suddenly works.